# How enable Advanced Google Services and use DriveApp clas in Google Appa Script

Tags: google-apps-script, service, google-drive-api

I am trying to learn Google Apps Script and working with DriveApp class. I try to create folders and files in Google Drive. But I am not able to run it. I create code and add  services I think is related with Google. Is there anything else that needs to be activated to make DriveApp. work ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `But I am not able to run it.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? And in your showing script in your image, when it is run, I think that a folder of `folderName` is created in the root folder. How about this? By the way, when you want to use Google Drive service (DriveApp), Drive API is not required to be enabled.

Comment: Sorry for bad explanation. No folder is created. It freezes on the second line "const folder = DriveApp.createFolder(folderName);"

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot find `Logger.log('Start');` in your showing script in your image. I apologize for this. From this situation, I'm worried that you actual script might be different from your showing script. How about this?

Comment: I tryed to make logs after every line (at the beggining of function, in the middle, at the end). All logs are recorded, but last log is not recorded: "Logger.log('Created folder ID ${folder.getId()}');"  - this record is missing  in log.  It means there is any problem with line "const folder = DriveApp.createFolder(folderName);"

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you provide your current script?

Comment: function cFolder()
{
Logger.log('Start');
const folderName = "Skritfolder";
Logger.log('Middle');
const folder = DriveApp.createFolder(folderName);
Logger.log('Created folder ID ${folder.getId()}');
}

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, `Logger.log('Created folder ID ${folder.getId()}')` is not correct if you want to use the template literal. Please modify to ``Logger.log(`Created folder ID ${folder.getId()}`)``. And, I think that your script creates a folder with the folder name `Skritfolder` in the root folder. So, I cannot understand the logic for `But I am not able to run it.`. I apologize for my poor skill.

Comment: Thanks for repairing. But this does not look to be the main reason. Even if I replace whole  line with simple line "Logger.log('End');" problem still persists.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Even if I replace whole line with simple line "Logger.log('End');" problem still persists.`, in your situation, how is your script run?

Comment: It's running from google spreadsheet file, where is menu "My Custom Menu" and submenu "Create folder" I click on.

Comment: Please learn how to  post code as text [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Help us add your code as text format code, also just to confirm the actual problem is that the folder is not created when using the custom menu you created, or is there a different issue/

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `It's running from google spreadsheet file, where is menu "My Custom Menu" and submenu "Create folder" I click on.`, if you are using your showing script, this process will create a folder. But you say `But this does not look to be the main reason.`, for example, you authorized the scopes when you run the script?